# Password is denied under certain circumstances

Tags: ssh, password, authentication

I have a raspberry pi which for a given user I can directly logon to the machine and I can also putty in.

But then I connect an Ethernet between the pi and Ubuntu laptop, execute `ip addr add 10.3.4.21/24 dev eth0`, and then `ssh myuser@10.3.4.21`, and it asks me for a password, but states "Permission denied".

Why?

Comment: `ssh -vvv myuser@10.3.4.21` for more info on the login process

Comment: All users are experiencing this behavior or only yours? The user has UID = 0 like root?

Comment: @StephenRauch  Thanks for the verbose suggestion.

Comment: @LucianoAndressMartini  No, normal user